# How do i connect My ESP8266 using arduino to my Flutter App. Complete Beginner here

Tags: arduino, flutter, esp8266

I wanted to send some data from my Arduino-uno to my flutter app over wifi. I am using ESP8266 wifi module for the same. I tried to find some online libraries, i found [wifi|Flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/wifi#-readme-tab-) and [connectivity|Flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity#-readme-tab-). I couldn't however get it to run.

I have installed the packages, added them to the pubspec.yaml file.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  wifi: ^0.1.4
  connectivity: ^0.3.2
```

I also tried the sample codes found in the package repositories,

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wifi/wifi.dart';

void main()=>runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  String ssid = await Wifi.ssid;

//Signal strength， 1-3，The bigger the number, the stronger the signal
  int level = await Wifi.level;

  String ip = await Wifi.ip;

  var result = await Wifi.connection('ssid', 'password');
  List<WifiResult> list = await Wifi.list('key');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('$level $list'),
    );
  }
}
```

but run into some errors such as (line numbers are at the end of each line)

```
error: A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'. (invalid_assignment at [all_tests_here1] lib\main.dart:7)
error: Unexpected text 'await'. (unexpected_token at [all_tests_here1] lib\main.dart:7)
error: Unexpected text 'await'. (unexpected_token at [all_tests_here1] lib\main.dart:10)
error: A value of type 'Future<int>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'. (invalid_assignment at [all_tests_here1] lib\main.dart:10)
error: A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'. (invalid_assignment at [all_tests_here1] lib\main.dart:12)
error: Unexpected text 'await'. (unexpected_token at [all_tests_here1] lib\main.dart:12)
error: Unexpected text 'await'. (unexpected_token at [all_tests_here1] lib\main.dart:14)
error: A value of type 'Future<List<WifiResult>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<WifiResult>'. (invalid_assignment at [all_tests_here1] lib\main.dart:15)
error: Unexpected text 'await'. (unexpected_token at [all_tests_here1] lib\main.dart:15)
```

I want to send all the sensor data(2 sensors) using wifi to the firebase, and then get it to the flutter app.
Me and my team are complete beginners, so please pardon any stupid mistakes,

Comment: It seems your statements are not enclosed in a class method or a function. Check the [dart style guides](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart), start with the flutter counter starter app and modify that, and update the question with your complete code - where there are errors with line numbers it helps us to know which line is which. (Aside - your imports are in an unconventional order. Start with the dart: ones, then put the package ones in alphabetical order. See the style guide.)

Comment: @RichardHeap i have updated the code, and added it here. Also, the line numbers are at the end of the error message.

Comment: My suggestion to start with the demo application that you get from `flutter create` still stands. This gives you a working framework that has state and a button, etc. As you modify it the compiler should warn you of errors as you type. You can also make use of Flutter's hot reload and restart to experiment iteratively and quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the error, it was caused by expected Future type being assigned on a String variable. Similar errors are thrown on other variables declared. You can either set the var as `dynamic` or set the expected type.

```dart
Future<String> getWifiSSID() async => await Wifi.ssid;
Future<int> getWifiSignalLevel() async => await Wifi.level;
Future<String> getWifiIp() async => await Wifi.ip;
Future<WifiState> getWifiAccess(String wifiSSID, String wifiPass) async =>
  await Wifi.connection(wifiSSID, wifiPass);

Future<List<WifiResult>> getWifiList() async => await Wifi.list('key');
```

Now to call the async functions, you can wait for their result on `then(value)` and optionally catch errors using `catchError(onError)`.

```dart
// Connect to wifi
getWifiAccess(SSID, pass)
  .then((wifiAccess) => debugPrint('wifiAccess: $wifiAccess'))
  .catchError((onError) => debugPrint('wifiAccess error: $onError'));

// fetch network SSID of current wifi connection
getWifiSSID()
  .then((wifiSSID) => debugPrint('wifiSSID: $wifiSSID'))
  .catchError((onError) => debugPrint('wifiSSID error: $onError'));

// fetch network signal level of current wifi connection
getWifiSignalLevel()
  .then((wifiSignalLevel) => debugPrint('wifiSignalLevel: $wifiSignalLevel'))
  .catchError((onError) => debugPrint('wifiSignalLevel error: $onError'));

// fetch network IP address
getWifiIp()
  .then((wifiIpAddress) => debugPrint('wifiIpAddress: $wifiIpAddress'))
  .catchError((onError) => debugPrint('wifiIpAddress error: $onError'));

// fetch list of access points (only works on Android)
getWifiList().then((wifiList) {
  wifiList.forEach((wifi) {
    debugPrint('wifiList: ${wifi.ssid} signal: ${wifi.level}');
  });
}).catchError((onError) => debugPrint('wifiList error: $onError'));
```

Edit: To add, you might also want to consider using [`wifi_info_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_info_flutter) plugin that's more up-to-date compared to the `wifi` plugin.